# Light Table auto close Parenthesis on Windows 7 International Spanish Keyboard

Tags: clojure, keyboard, lighttable, keymaps

I'm using a International Spanish Keyboard with deadsunkeys the following code works for "'(){} but not for [], any clues?.

To test I used:

```
[:editor.keys.normal "ctrl-`" :tabs.next]
```

and nothing happened.

```
Light Table 0.7.2
user.keymaps

;; Auto Close
[:editor.keys.normal "\"" (:editor.repeat-pair "\"")]
[:editor.keys.normal "'" (:editor.repeat-pair "'")]
[:editor.keys.normal "(" (:editor.open-pair "(")]
[:editor.keys.normal ")" (:editor.close-pair ")")]

[:editor.keys.normal "ctrl-alt-[" (:editor.open-pair "[")]
[:editor.keys.normal "ctrl-alt-]" (:editor.close-pair "]")]

[:editor.keys.normal "ctrl-alt-'" (:editor.open-pair "{")]
[:editor.keys.normal "ctrl-'" (:editor.open-pair "{")]
[:editor.keys.normal "ctrl-alt-ç" (:editor.close-pair "}")]
[:editor.keys.normal "ctrl-ç" (:editor.close-pair "}")]
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I confirm it all works fine on Mac OS 10.9.5 with LT 0.7.2, just rambling, could you try with es-spanish layout rather than es-international if it's available?

Comment: Tryed, and also tested with a custom layout, closed LT between switches.